# Monodevelop - when does it save csproj files?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xamarin

When MonoDevelop crashes (somewhat often unfortunately) I usually have to re-do changes to the project that seem to not be written to disk. As a result my work flow has become - change project, restart monodevelop (hoping changes are saved during a close). I find this to be a little frustrating. Ideally there would be an explicit save button in the UI so that I know for a fact my changes are written when I expected them to be. I am not sure where to file enhancements requests - through Xamarin (since this is monodevelop with monotouch)? Any chance someone has written an Add-In to do this?

Comment: file a bug/enh request with Xamarin

Comment: Yeah, I'd say file a bug, try a complete reinstall of MD.

Comment: Do you build your app frequently? I would think you would be building your app fairly often--working in the simulator makes this a bit quicker.

Answer (score 0):

If everything is OK with your MD installation the Save All command/button should save all the project files and solution. I regularly use this command as a safeguard. On my experience just hitting Save only saves the file you are editing on the moment, keeping the solution and project files unsaved.